# ajax get checkbox name which is an array

Tags: javascript, php, checkbox

*updated* 
I'm using while loop to display checkbox, the value of the checkbox is the amount.  The codes can now display the total value when a checkbox is checked through the ajax function. During form submit, how do i obtain the $ID of checked value? As the name of the checkbox is not an array, i have no idea how to do that other way. Please help :'( Thanks in advance! 

PHP:

```
<table>
<form name="listForm">
<?php
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
$ID = $row['ID'];
$amount = $row['amount'];
?>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="payID" data-payment-id="<?php echo $ID;?>" value="<?php echo $amount;?>" onclick="calculate();"></td>

</tr>
<?php
}?>
</table>
</form>
```

javascript:

```
function calculate(){
document.listForm.payID.value = '';
var sum = 0;
var count = 0;
for (i=0;i< document.listForm.payID.length ; i++) {
if (document.listForm.payID[i].checked) {
sum = sum + parseInt(document.listForm.payID[i].value);
count = count + 1;
}
}

document.getElementById('payable').innerHTML = "Total record chosen= "+ count +"<br>Total amount= " + sum + "<br>";
}
```

Comment: `document.listForm.payID[i].value` but `payID` is not an array - `name="payID"`

Comment: i have changed it a bit, by now i can display the total value when checkbox is checked, but  i can't get the $ID after form submit

Comment: I'm a bit confused... where does AJAX come into play here? And also how do you want to be storing the data-payment-id in the end, in a javascript array or what?

Comment: @Logan Bentley i edited the codes so ajax is not used right now. And my problem is i wish to get all the $ID of checked values when form is submitted. I'm new to PHP and not really know what to do. Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the "data-payment-id" attribute from the checkboxes that are clicked as well. I'd store them in an array, then json stringify it to be sent in your form.

**Javascript:**

```
function calculate(){
        document.listForm.payID.value = '';
        var sum = 0;
        var count = 0;
        var idList = [];
        for (i=0;i< document.listForm.payID.length ; i++) {
            if (document.listForm.payID[i].checked) {
                sum = sum + parseInt(document.listForm.payID[i].value);
                count = count + 1;
                idList.push(document.listForm.payID[i].getAttribute('data-payment-id'));
            }
        }

        document.getElementById('sum').value = sum;
        document.getElementById('count').value = count;
        document.getElementById('idList').value = JSON.stringify(idList);
        return true;
    }
```

And then for your form, update it to have the hidden inputs and the onsubmit function - here's what I was using for a test:

**HTML Form:**

```
<form name="listForm" action="aoeu.php" method="post" onsubmit="calculate()">
    <input type='checkbox' name="payID" value='1' data-payment-id='aaa'> 1<br>
    <input type='checkbox' name="payID" value='2' data-payment-id='bbb'> 2<br>
    <input type='checkbox' name="payID" value='3' data-payment-id='ccc'> 3<br>
    <input type='hidden' id='sum' name='sum'>
    <input type='hidden' id='count' name='count'>
    <input type='hidden' id='idList' name='idList'>
    <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Then just make sure to `json_decode()` the idList you get in your PHP post.

Comment: thanks! this works! but how do i get the array idList from PHP script?

Comment: @Nichole It really depends on your setup. Are you wanting to submit the form the regular way, or by AJAX?

Comment: just submitting the form in the regular way

Comment: @Nichole - I've updated the code so you can see how it would work for a form submit. Let me know if anything is unclear :)

Comment: thanks for you help ! I had figure out that putting the hidden input field which store the idList in the while loop cause problem in getting the value using $_POST. After i moved the hidden text input out of the loop, i can get the value now!

Answer (score 0):

I have updated now. In your php code amend this line:

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="payID" data-payment-id="<?php echo $ID;?>" id="payment_id[]" onClick="calculate()" value="<?php echo $amount;?>" >
```

And your Javascript function:

```
function calculate(){
    var sum = 0;
    var count = 0;
    var a1=document.listForm['payment_id[]'];
    for(i=0;i<a1.length;i++){
        if (a1[i].checked){
             sum += parseInt(a1[i].value);
             count = count + 1;
        }


    }

    document.getElementById('payable').innerHTML = "Total record chosen= "+ count +"<br>Total amount= " + sum + "<br>";
}
```

Comment: I don't think this will work if I understand the question. It only will give you the $ID (payID) of the element clicked, not of all the checkboxes currently marked. That means on deselection as well it would be saying this is the selected ID.